# C# How can the selected row from DataGridView show in textBox1?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

[image]

> Hello I am trying to show the selected row from the DataGridView1 to textBox1.
> The Data shown in the DataGridView is from the database "LocalDB".
> I am just trying to get the "CustomersName" to show in textBox1.
> Because I will need the "CustomersName" shown in the textBox1 so I can delete it from database.
> I am not yet sure but here is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                textBox1.Text = row.Cells["CustomersName"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try the SelectionChanged event? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged?view=net-5.0

Comment: I will use SelectionChanged Event?

Comment: Is it throwing exception? Because code if OK, the only thing witch can be not good is name of column "CustomersName" - check if column has same name

Comment: **Hello Thank you! I changed my code to:**
           `int index = e.RowIndex;// get the Row Index
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
            textBox1.Text = selectedRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();`